# Is SSH history local or its server side?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, putty

I use Putty to access my dedicated servers trough SSH. When i click up arrow couple times i can see commands that i put in yesterday or at previous session. Do they stay locally or on server side? How can i clear this list or previous commands? So next time if someone else logs in he won't see what i was doing.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply remove this file for now. And to prevent it being saved next time, you could put `unset HISTFILE` into your .bash_profile. A bit more drastic is `ln -sf /dev/null .bash_history`. You'll still have command history during your sessions, but the file isn't saved anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The history is kept in (most likely) a file in your home directory, ~/.bash_history, which is on the server you connect to. Other users shouldn't have access to your .bash_history, and you can just clear the content of that to clear out the history.